# how to acces host services in virtual box with out additional networking

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I have ubuntu 10.04 and virtual box running win xp now i want to test my page layout in ie so i want to access apache from with in my virtual box how can i set up this with out additional networking on the host (i.e. i want to have some kind'a peer to peer connection between the host and the guest)

Comment: Although I have answered your question, it would be much better suited to http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com I think.

Comment: Please don't close and reopen your question on another site. If enough people agree it belongs there instead, it will be automatically migrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your local (host) machine's Apache server from your Virtual Box using the default gateway of the virtual machine. If you type `ipconfig` at the command prompt, you will find that IP address.

Once you have that, just browse to that IP and folder in IE. (Or any other browser you might have installed, for that matter.)

Comment: when i mean with out additional networking i mean with out another node which in turn means my default gateway is my host(the ubuntu  ) ....

Comment: @jspeshu I'm not quite sure what you mean in your comment. But yes, your default gateway in the virutal machine _is_ your Ubuntu.

Comment: here is my conf for ubuntu , auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

then i set up win xp  with ip 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1 ........ but i cannot ping any of them

Comment: In that case, try VSU's suggestion of using the NAT networking option for your virtual machine. I think it's the default option, as I never do any advanced setup of my VirtualBox VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown XP and delete all networking options for the VM from VirtualBox. Create a new networking option (by default), this is NAT. Start the XP VM and install VirtualBox Guest Additions.  Rrefer the VirtualBox help file for instructions. You need to first mount the Vbox Guest Additions ISO as a CD-ROM drive. Restart the VM. Your XP guest and the Ubuntu host will be given IP on the same subnet. You can access Apache websites running on the host by typing the host IP address in the URL.